# S Cannot be resolved. Clojure. Cursive

Tags: clojure, cursive

Here's my code

```
(declare PutProp) 
(defn DefList! 
  [L] 
  (let [V (first L)] 
    (map ([fn [S K]] [PutProp S V K] (next L)))))
```

L is a structured list.

The first atom is a Value, followed by Symbol/Key pairs for assigning metadata on the given Symbol with the given Value and the given Key.
PutProp seems to be defined with no problem.

What I WANT it to do is call PutProp repeatedly until the L list is exhausted.

Cursive says "S cannot be resolved." "K cannot be resolved." for the map statement.

I'm new to Cursive, Clojure...

I copied this form straight out of ClojureDocs for the map statement.
I don't see why S and K can't be resolved. I'm clearly clueless. Any clues?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `fn` definition is wrong - it looks like it should be `(map (fn [[S K]] (PutProp S V K)) (next L))`

Comment: Hi, could you give me a sample of calling, please?

Comment: Nicholas, thank you for your time and attempt to help.